# String array values not printing properly

Tags: c, arrays

I am rather new to C and am probably doing something stupid but I can't find out why my string array isn't keeping the previous values while the grade is keeping all the values entered:

```
for(int i=0; i <noOfStudents; i++)
{
    do{
        printf("Please enter Student Full Name.");
        //read string till enter
        scanf(" %[^\n]", &studentFullName);
        if(studentFullName == "")
        {
            printf("Invalid Student Name!\n\n");
            getchar();
        }
        else
        {
            names[i] = studentFullName;
            validStudentName = 1;
        }
    }while(validStudentName != 1);

    do{
        printf("Please enter Student Grade.");
        scanf_s(" %d", &grade);
        if(grade < -1 && grade >100)
        {
            printf("Invalid Student Grade!\n\n");
            getchar();
        }
        else
        {
            grades[i] = grade;
            validGrade = 1;
        }
    }while(validGrade != 1);

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You 'd be surprised to learn that `studentFullName == ""` does not work. You need to use `strcmp` instead, or in this case the more suitable `if(!strlen(studentFullName))`.

Comment: Could you tell us where you allocate `studentFullName` and how you do it?

Comment: Also you might want to think about the expression that you are using to attempt to check for invalid grades...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grade` is an integer. When you do:

```
int a;
int b = 3;
a = b;
b = 4;
```

then `a` continues to be 3, because integers are copied.

studentFullName is, however, a pointer. Just like integers, pointers are copied. However, the data the pointer points to *is not*. So, basically, you've got your entire names[] array as a bunch of pointers, all pointing to the exact same data.

There are several functions that will copy the pointed-to data for you, the one you're looking for is probably `strdup`. Note that you must `free` all the pointers you get back from `strdup`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the strdup it saved me since i couldn't understand what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 2):

In short, pointers. You're just assigning the same pointer to each element in the `names` array. You need to allocate separate strings for each one.

Additionally, you have a bug: `studentFullName == ""` will never return true. You should be using `strcmp(studentFullName, "") == 0`.

Oh, and additionally, you should be using `scanf(" %[^\n]", studentFullName);`, without the reference operator, since otherwise you're doing something incredibly undefined with your memory, assuming `studentFullName` is allocated as a `char *`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on string comparisons in C also my char is 40 is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `strcmp` or `stricmp` to compare strings in C because `studentFullName` is simply the location of the start of the character buffer in memory.

It's not valid to write:

```
if(studentFullName == "")
```

Instead, you can write

```
if(strcmp(studentFullName, ""))
```

Similarly, `names[i] = studentFullName;` isn't making a copy of `studentFullName`, it's setting `names[i]` to point at the `studentFullName` buffer, which you overwrite each time through the loop.

To make copies of "strings" (or better thought of as character buffers), you should use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

```
if(grade < -1 && grade >100)
```

I think you want to get the grade between -1 and 100. "&&" means "and", 
as your code, it means grade should less-than "-1" and greater-than "100" at 
the same time. So, it always equal to :

```
if (false)
```

So the "else" condition is always running.